# Extend Joomla mod_latest_news, but getting articles for today only

Tags: php, joomla

How can I add a condition to the ContentModel of Articles in the my new module (derived from mod_latest_news) so that it only fetches articles created today. I have tried adding the following to the `helper.php` file of the module:

```
// Date must where created today
$model->setState('a.created', date('Y-m-d'));
```

But it doesn't seem to help. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the popular tags module, it has time based options.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$model->setState('filter.date_filtering', 'relative');
$model->setState('filter.relative_date', 1);
```

Comment: Hi, I use your code, and it's working good until I upgrade to joomla 3.2.2 today. I received error message Notice: Undefined variable: nowDate in xxx/components/com_content/models/articles.php on line 471

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xxx/components/com_content/models/articles.php on line 546
 when login as an admin in the frontend. Any idea?
This is my complete question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641365/joomla-3-2-2-issue-with-filter-date-filtering-relative  Thanks!