# Joomla 3.2.2 issue: Notice: Undefined variable: nowDate /components/com_content/models/articles.php

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

I have modified my joomla latest news module to make it displaying only articles from the latest month by adding these lines to the helper.php

```
$model->setState('filter.date_filtering', 'relative');
$model->setState('filter.relative_date', 30);
```

It works good until I upgraded my joomla installation to the latest Joomla 3.2.2 today.
It works properly for public access and registered user, but when I login as a admin user in the frontend it returns a blank output and when I set the error reporting to the development level it returns these error messages :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: nowDate in xxx/components/com_content/models/articles.php on line 471

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xxx/components/com_content/models/articles.php on line 546

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xxx/modules/mod_articles_latest/helper.php on line 105

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xxx/modules/mod_articles_latest/tmpl/default.php on line 13
```

When I looked at the com_content/models/articles.php, and comparing it with the old 3.2.1 version I found that this new line added in the j 3.2.2 version :

```
if ((!$user->authorise('core.edit.state', 'com_content')) && (!$user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_content'))) {
```

If I delete this line then everything back to normal.

My questions is, is it something considered a joomla 3.2.2 bug or not? If it's not, how can I modify the module code to allow me displaying only articles from the latest 30 months without modifying the articles.php?

Thank you

Comment: Did you hack the core module or did you make a copy of it?

Comment: I hacked it. Anyway it looks like this is a joomla 3.2.2 bug as I found a same issue in joomla article category module

Comment: In that case, I recommend submitting it as a bug report: http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemBrowse&tracker_id=8103

Comment: Here is the tracker id: http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=33248&start=8425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've submitted a patch for this issue.

[See the issue tracker item.](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=33248)

Here is the PR and the patch:

For Joomla 3.2

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3084

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3084.diff

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3084.patch

For Joomla 2.5.x

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3085

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3085.diff

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3085.patch

Comment: The changes have been accepted and tested and it will most likely ship with the next release.